# How to connect Terraform to Kubernetes cluster

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, terraform

I am trying to connect terraform to a Kubernetes cluster, but the documentation on Terraform is not clear on which client certificates I should use for TLS connection. Since I am new to both Kubernetes and Terraform, I could not figure that out:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

  client_certificate     = "${file("~/.kube/client-cert.pem")}"
  client_key             = "${file("~/.kube/client-key.pem")}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${file("~/.kube/cluster-ca-cert.pem")}"
}
```

in the /etc/kubernetes/pki there is more than one certificate and key ( front-proxy-client, api-server-client, api-server-kubelet-client ), which one should I use to Allow terraform to connect to my cluster ?

---

**Edit:** Here is the kubernetes version ( output of kubectl version )

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:45:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:35:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: How did you setup your cluster? Are you using cloud-provider option or some bare-metal? Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: I edited the question with the version. I am deploying kubernetes on AWS EC2 instances ( not the EKS service ). I followed the simple steps of setting up the cluster using kubeadm init.

Comment: The cluster is working fine but the I cannot connect Terraform as I keep getting no response from the cluster endpoint. I also double checked the inbound rules and I am allowing all traffic to all IPs ( ipv4 and ipv6 ).

Comment: I am executing the terraform script from my own computer. It's not joined in the cluster in any sense, it's neither the worker or the master node. Also I don't have kubectl installed on my computer. I thought Terraform will just use the config file and use the tools on the cluster. Do I need to install kubectl on my local computer maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason. It was not connected to Terraform. The problem is when I setup my cluster I used the option --apiserver-advertise-address=<MASTER_NODE_PRIVATE_IP> in the kubeadm init command, but when I used --control-plane-endpoint=<MASTER_NODE_PUBLIC_IP>, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have kubectl configured in the client-side where you run terraform? In that case, you can use the same configs you used for kubectl. Like this

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path    = "~/.kube/config"
  config_context = "my-context"
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-first-namespace"
  }
}
```

more details - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs#statically-defined-credentials

If not configuring kubectl is quite easy. You can refer to the docs of your flavor/version of kubernetes. You may also use the same kubeconfig file from an existing kubectl enabled client. Make sure to handle the keys securely.

A few different methods are mentioned here - https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/kubernetes-provider?in=terraform/use-case#configure-the-provider

If you are using a cloud provider flavor like EKS, gcloud you explore the cloud-specific plugins too.

Comment: I followed that tutorial but still no luck. I am using the kubernetes context ( the default context : kubernetes-admin@kubernetes ) and I did not create my own. Could that be the  reason ?

Comment: If you have only one context in your kubeconfig you do not need to mention 'config_context' at all. Just mentioning 'config_path' works. You are able to connect to the cluster using kubectl from your computer right?